# Ink - Splash drawing using OpenGL Shaders

Tags: ios, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to create ink splash lines using OpenGL.

Basically I want to "render" to texture, so that I can use this textures later.
The variation I need in the line is giving by an array of values. For example,
assuming an horizontal line is required i would have an array like this:

8 7 4 2 2 2 3 4 5 6 8 9

And the result would be a line similar to a brush stroke in where higher values
represent "more ink" at that area, thus looking fatter, and smaller values looking
slimmer.

I need to make this iPhone compatible so I have to use OpenGL ES 2.0, but I'm a bit
lost to what technique I should be using. I thought that perhaps using a sprite and
drawing it multiple times on a random position (like a rain of dots) that would vary
in with if the number is big?

Ive read several papers and they do show the results i want to get but they don't talk
much about the rendering part, or how they are showing this type of drawing.

This is an example of the effect I want to achieve, the only difference is that i would
like the "splashes" to be continuous (no white between them)

[image: http://image.yaymicro.com/rz_512x512/2/6d0/black-drop-ink-splatter-splash-26d0e40.jpg]

Unlike the image shown, direction is not needed, since it will be drawn for a texture to
be used. It should always be horizontal in a given area (256x64) for example.

Comment: So basically you want some custom draw tool which would draw splashes instead of say straight lines ?

Comment: Sort of, I need to perform this on the GPU because the values are line dependant and constantly change with each new line. And I need to pass this texture to be rendered in the 3D world. The user doesn't have control over the drawing, it just has to be able to vary with the given parameters.